# Set default value for entity type in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, types

I couldn't figure out how to make a default value for an entity type in symfony2.  My code looked like this:

```
$rewardChoice = $this->createFormBuilder($reward)
    ->add('reward_name', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'FuelFormBundle:Reward',
        'property' => 'reward_name',
        'data' => 2,
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')
                ->where('r.active = 1')
                ->groupBy('r.reward_id')
                ->orderBy('r.reward_name', 'DESC');

        },
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

However you need to hand in the object you are working with to make it work.  My answer is below.

I found a lot of different answers on this but they all restructured the way the form was built.  This was much easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I found a lot of answers to make this work but all of them seemed to restructure the form to be built in another way however I found that setting the object in works best so I figured I would post my solution incase anyone ran into the issue again.

Here is my code in the controller.

```
// this is setting up a controller and really isn't important 
$dbController = $this->get('database_controller');

// this is getting the user id based on the hash passed by the url from the
// database controller
$user_id = $dbController->getUserIdByHash($hash);

// this is getting the Reward Entity.  A lot of times you will see it written as 
// $reward = new Reward however I am setting info into reward right away in this case
$reward = $dbController->getRewardByUserId($user_id);


$rewardChoice = $this->createFormBuilder($reward)
    ->add('reward_name', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'FuelFormBundle:Reward',
        'property' => 'reward_name',

        // I pass $reward to data to set the default data.  Whatever you
        // assign to $reward will set the default value.  
        'data' => $reward,  
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er){
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('r')
                    ->where('r.active = 1')
                    ->groupBy('r.reward_id')
                    ->orderBy('r.reward_name', 'DESC');
        },
    ))
    ->getForm();
```

I hope this make things more clear. I saw a lot of the same question but none with this solution.

Answer (score 6):

The best way to do this is to set reward name before creating the form. For example:

```
$reward->setRewardName('your_relationship_reference_here');

$rewardChoice = $this->createFormBuilder($reward)
```

Using the `data` field can cause problems.

Comment: Yes, it seems that your solution is the most elegant one. 
Regarding the `data`:
_"...This means the object value is also overriden when the form edits an already persisted object, causing it to lose its persisted value when the form is submitted."_ [[1](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#data)]

On the other hand `empty_data` doesn't affect the display of the form - it just provides the _default_ value on submit. [[2](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#empty_data)]

Comment: Yes, this should be done only when creating new entity, when you edit don’t set default value.

Answer (score 3):

For symfony 4 we can use 'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',

```
->add('reward_name', EntityType::class, array(
                    'class' => Reward::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'name',
                    'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
                ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize value from the form's target object

```
$article=2/*Id of item that you wont to set as default*/    
$stock->setArtigo($this
                ->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:Artigo')
                ->find($article));

            $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\StockType', $stock);
```