# Default value in EntityType

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have an EntityType in my form and I would like set a default selected value, it's possible ?

This is my code in my FormType :

```
->add('pays', EntityType::class, [
             'class' => Pays::class,
             'choice_label' => function (Pays $pays) {
                 return $pays->getNomFrFr();
             },
        ])
```

The value of each option of the select in HTML match with the id in my database :

```
<label for="boutique_pays" class="required">Pays</label><select id="boutique_pays" name="boutique[pays]">
    <option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="2">Albanie</option>
    <option value="3">Antarctique</option>
    <option value="4">Algérie</option>
    ...
    <option value="237">Wallis et Futuna</option>
    <option value="238">Samoa</option>
    <option value="239">Yémen</option>
    <option value="240">Serbie-et-Monténégro</option>
    <option value="241">Zambie</option>
</select>
```

I would like set the selected value to '75' (France), it's possible ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#data) and [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577982/set-default-value-for-entity-type-in-symfony2)

Answer (score 0):

Pass EntityManager and your default choice objectID when create form type.

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(YourClass)->find($id);
$yourDefaultValue = $repository->getId();


$form = $this->createForm(new YourTypeType($entityManager), $yourEntity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('route_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
            'your_default_value' => $yourDefaultValue,
        ));
```

add constructor in your form type.then replace your code...

```
  private $em;

  public function __construct($em) {
      $this->em = $em;
  }

  ->add('pays', EntityType::class, [
         'class' => Pays::class,
         'choice_label' => function (Pays $pays) {
             return $pays->getNomFrFr();
         },
         'data'=>$this->em->getReference("YourEntity",$options['your_default_value'])

    ])
```

and finally, add your_default_value empty array in your setDefaultOptions

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface 
 $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'YourEntity',
            'your_default_value' => array()
        ));
    }
```